# Trouble With If statement PHP

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I have been scripting PHP for for about 9 months now and im starting to run into a problem with my if conditions. This has never happened before.

```
if ($reason != "9ee1e1f4fbf1"){
    XXXXXXXXX
}
```

I even tried putting the 9ee1ef4fbf1 in parenthesis and that didnt work.
i keep getting this:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in /home/content/49/549/html/index.php on line 21
```

Comment: The problem is more likely to be in the lines immediately prior to your if statement, perhaps a missing ; on the previous line. Please post a line or two before as well.

Comment: Can you give us the code (or pseudo-code as accurate as possible [change variable names if they are sensitive]) above this statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in the line **above** the if. Maybe forgot a semicolon?

Comment: Yes, that's the semi I meant. :)

Comment: correct.  Although, it may not be immediately above the if, it is somewhere above it.

Answer (score 1):

Please post the lines before the `if` statement. Usually, when you get an `unexpected ____` error in PHP, it means you left out a semi-colon or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The `T_IF` token is unexpected, probably because PHP was in a parsing state that wasn't finished by an ending delimiter (perhaps the end of line semi-colon (`;`)).

Answer (score 0):

You should look at anything before the if, maybe you are missing a semicolon(;).